# Con Django 'str' object is not callable en class based-views

Tags: python, django

Tengo este problema cuando quiero acceder a una URL que me dice que es `str object is no callable` seguramente tengo algo mal en las urls o una configuración de esas pero la verdad es que he revisado bien todos los archivos y no entiendo muy por qué se debe este error.

Dejo los códigos que creo estan influyendo en algo del error. Si falta algunos más decirme y lo agrego también. También si pudieran darme una explicación del error para conocer mejor el por qué. Sé que es un dato que python no lo esta leyendo correctamente.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birthday = models.DateField()
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .models import UserProfile

class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'userprofiles/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = 'UserForm'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 

from .views import UserCreateView

app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/', UserCreateView.as_view(), name="user_create"),
]
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'users:user_create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Crear Usuario</button>
</form>
```

Si alguno pudiera ayudarme con esto lo agradeceria bastante.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el atributo `form_class` de tu vista `UserCreateView`.

Cuando se ejecuta la vista, se llama a un método llamado `.get_form()` en el que se ejecuta una linea similar a esta:

```
self.form_class(...)
```

Como ves, crea una instancia de lo que haya en el atributo de clase `form_class`, como tu tienes ahí un string: `'UserForm'` no se puede hacer un llamado (osea instanciarlo con `()`) a un string. En su lugar debes importar tu `UserForm` y colocar la clase como valor en `form_class`:

```
from my_app.forms import UserForm  # ruta de ejemplo

class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'userprofiles/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = UserForm  # sin comillas

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Cierto, que tonto fui :C Gracias por la respuesta @Gocht, ahora me queda la duda de una cosa y no sé si puedes ayudarme con eso también. El formulario me muestra los campos que tengo en el modelo, pero puedo usar de alguna manera los campos del usuario que trae django por defecto(username, email, first_name, last_name, etc) y mostrar todo eso en un solo formulario. Saludos!

Comment: @ikenshu sería bueno que publiques una nueva pregunta con todo lo relacionado al problema que tienes con los formularios. Saludos.

Comment: Sí, voy a ver si puedo solucionarle en un futuro y si no puedo realizo una pregunta de nuevo. Gracias :P