# Python&SQL TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: pandas, jupyter, sqlite3

En el script que muestro a continuación, realizo una importación de módulos, conecto con la base de datos sqlite3, creo un dataframe y dos tablas. Lanzo una consulta para tratar de obtener los datos de precipitación entre dos fechas dadas y me devuelve el error mencionado.

```
# Importación de módulosimport sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Conectamos con la base de datos
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('pybodb.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

# Creamos un DataFrame
# fechas para cada día del 2014
fechas = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2014, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2014, 12, 31))

# Temperatura media diaria durante 2014 en algún lugar del hemisferio Norte
tmed = (np.random.randint(-5, 5, size = 365) +
        20 * np.cos(np.arange(0 - 180, 365 - 180) * 2 * np.pi / 365)
        + 10)

# Precipitación acumulada en 24h
prec = (20 * np.abs(np.random.randn(365) *
        np.cos(np.arange(0, 365) * 2 * np.pi / 365)))

# Sensor que midió la temperatura
marcaT = np.random.choice(['marcaT1', 'marcaT2', 'marcaT3'], size = 365)

# Sensor midió la precipitación
marcaP = np.random.choice(['marcaP1', 'marcaP2'], size = 365)

# Creamos el dataframe y lo guardamos en una tabla llamada 'datos'
df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.array([fechas.values, tmed, prec, marcaT, marcaP]).T,
        columns = ['fecha', 'tmedia','precipitacion','sensorT','sensorP'])
df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'])
df.to_sql('datos', con = conn, dtype = {'time': 'TIMESTAMP'})

# Creamos una segunda tabla
# fechas para cada día del 2014
sensores = ['marcaT1', 'marcaT2', 'marcaT3',
            'marcaP1', 'marcaP2']
# Precisión de los sensores
precision = [0.1, 0.5, 1,
             2, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'sensores': sensores, 'precision': precision})
df.to_sql('sensores', con = conn)

# Datos de precipitación entre dos fechas
df = pd.read_sql(
    ("SELECT fecha, precipitacion FROM ")
    ("datos WHERE fecha BETWEEN ")
    ("'2014-06-01' AND '2014-07-01';"), 
    conn
)
df
```

Me devuelve el error:

```
<>:2: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:2: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
/tmp/ipykernel_11717/2898327354.py:2: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  ("SELECT fecha, precipitacion FROM ")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11717/2898327354.py in <module>
      1 df = pd.read_sql(
----> 2     ("SELECT fecha, precipitacion FROM ")
      3     ("datos WHERE fecha BETWEEN ")
      4     ("'2014-06-01' AND '2014-07-01';"),
      5     conn

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

¿Cuál es la explicación?. Agradeceré ayuda

Comment: La query multilinea te sugiero que los construyas afuera de la invocación a `read_sql()`, crea una variable, por ej `SQL` con la misma y se la pasas a la función.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Con Django 'str' object is not callable en class based-views](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22180/con-django-str-object-is-not-callable-en-class-based-views)

Comment: @kemilbeltre, Como he comentado en el texto,es mi primer paso en python&sql. Aún no  se analizar identificar en tu aportación una respuesta a mi pregunta. Tomo nota del enlace, para volver a ella cuando avance un poco más. Gracias